# asp.net radio buttons show/hide dropdownlist after check/uncheck

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have been trying to create a radio button that shows/hides the two drop-down lists when they are unchecked and checked.

My problem is that whenever I try to check another radio button, the drop-down list for the other radio button does not hide as intended. For example, if I checked `rbtnTwocolor`, the drop-down list for `rbtnOnecolor` does not hide.

I wanted to use radio button list but I couldn't insert a drop-down list in between the radio button list items.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnFullColor" Text="Full-Color" runat="server" GroupName="rbtnlistColors" /><br />
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnTwoColor" Text="Two-Color" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#twocolor" runat="server" GroupName="rbtnlistColors" /><br />
<div id="twocolor" class="collapse">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTwoColor" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnOneColor" Text="One-Color" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#onecolor" runat="server" GroupName="rbtnlistColors" /><br />
<div id="onecolor" class="collapse">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOneColor" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

for show/hide dropdown when select radiobutton , you can use ways below :

1: use jquery in client side:

```js
   <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#rbtnTwoColor').change(
                function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $('#twocolor').show();
                        $('#onecolor').hide();
                    }
                });

            $('#rbtnOneColor').change(
                function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                        $('#onecolor').show();
                        $('#twocolor').hide();
                    }
                });
    });

</script>
```

2: use server side event (OnCheckedChanged):

markup:

```html
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnFullColor" Text="Full-Color" runat="server" GroupName="rbtnlistColors" /><br />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnTwoColor" Text="Two-Color" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#twocolor"runat="server" GroupName="rbtnlistColors"  OnCheckedChanged="rbtnTwoColor_CheckedChanged"  AutoPostBack="true" /><br />
        <div id="twocolor" class="collapse">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTwoColor" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnOneColor" Text="One-Color" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#onecolor" runat="server" GroupName="rbtnlistColors"  OnCheckedChanged="rbtnOneColor_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  /><br />
        <div id="onecolor" class="collapse">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOneColor" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
```

and code behind:

```
    protected void rbtnTwoColor_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlTwoColor.Visible = true;
        ddlOneColor.Visible = false;
    }

    protected void rbtnOneColor_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlOneColor.Visible = true;
        ddlTwoColor.Visible = false;
    }
```

3: use javascript in client side:
add below code to rbtnTwoColor radiobutton

```js
 onclick="twoColorClick()"
```

add below code to rbtnOneColor radiobutton

```js
     onclick="oneColorClick()"
```

now in end of body tag add this code

```js
<script>

        function oneColorClick() {
            document.getElementById('onecolor').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('twocolor').style.display = 'none';
        }

        function twoColorClick() {
            document.getElementById('twocolor').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('onecolor').style.display = 'none';
        }

    </script>
```

good luck

Comment: Sorry but both solutions didn't work. When i used the client side script, both radio buttons and dropdown lists stayed the same. (whenever i choose the other radio button, the dropdownlist doesn't hide. vice versa). On the other hand, i tried running the server side events, the page refreshes when ever i choose another radio button. I think this is because i have AutoPostBack="true" but i put it into false, it doesn't do anything

Comment: if you want page not refresh , you should not use server side event. for that you say client side method not work maybe that is because jquery  not add reference. check it if not add reference , add reference for jquery or use javascript method

Comment: The javascript solution works but i am encountering a new problem. Whenever i choose the the rbtnTwoColor after i chose rbtnOneColoe this happens: http://imgur.com/a/rhaN7 .